# Clarification in Obj C Blocks

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

Why this is an Error ?

```
float (^isFloat)(float) = ^(float d)
{
    return d*2.0;
};
```

At the sometime, the following is error free,

```
float (^isFloat)(float) = ^(float d)
{
    return d;
};
```

PLease help me understand.

Comment: What error message is reported?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your return type on the first block is incorrect.

You defined the block to return a `float`, but you multiplied a `float` by a `double`. If you change it to `d * 2.0f` everything should work just fine.

Comment: To add: Floating-point constants are doubles unless specified otherwise.

Comment: beauty. Very nice to know that we have to add the f in the end. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question : when its mentioned as "d * 2.0f" what does it mean to the compiler ? Kind of type casting with the f in the end?